# Finding the determinant and trace of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, trace

> Let $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be the linear map that assigns to each point in $\mathbb R^2$ its reflection along the $x$-axis.

My questions:

- What is the determinant of $T$?
- What is trace of $T$ ?

My try:

My answer was the determinant is $2$  and trace is zero, i.e., I take  $(1,1)$   and its reflect image on $x$-axis is $(1,-1)$. Is my answer correct? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you tell what's the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How did you come up with your answer? Have you checked it for plausibility? For instance, the determinant of a linear transformation can be interpreted as an area scaling factor. Does it seem reasonable to you that reflecting a region doubles its area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $T(1,0)=(1,0)$ and $T(0,1)=(0,-1)$, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the canonical basis is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Therefore, the trace is $0$ and the determinant is $-1$.

Comment: thanks a lot @jose carlos santos

Comment: @legohlegoh If my answer was useful, then please mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: i dont know where i have to mark it ,, i didnot see the mark option